# showing $I_{c,d}$ is not a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Given the ring $R:=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f $ is continous$\}$ we define for $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ where $c\neq d$ , the ideal $I_{c,d}:=\{f\in R|f(c)=f(d)=0\} \subset R$. I have to show that $I_{c,d}$ is not a prime ideal.

My attempt is to find a counterexample:

Let $R$ be $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Then $f=(x-c)(x-d)$ with $f \in I_{c,d}$ but $(x-c) \notin I_{c,d}$ and $(x-d) \notin I_{c,d}$. So it's not a prime ideal. Is this enough? Or is there a better way to show it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a correct answer, when solving this kind of problem you can also consider the idea of taking the quotien ring and check whether or not it's a domain.

Comment: Thanks! How would it look like here? You mean $R/I_{c,d}$ is isomorphic to a non-integral domain?

Comment: Was an advice for the future since a direct proof was an easy way tho verify the statement. And yes, you find nonzero divisors in the quotient ring and you conclude ;)